# Is this a bad Moq setup or a deficiency in Moq?

Tags: c#, moq

I am attempting to test the following code:

```
public async Task<Activity> Get(long ID, Recruiter User, bool IsArchived = false)
{
    Activity result = await collection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == ID && x.Recruiter.CompanyID == User.CompanyID && (!x.Archived || IsArchived));
    return result;
}
```

With the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDoesThings()
{
    long ID = 1;
    bool IsArchived = false;
    Recruiter User = new Recruiter()
    {
        CompanyID = 1
    }; 

    ActivitiesMock.Setup(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == ID && y.Recruiter.CompanyID == User.CompanyID && (!y.Archived || IsArchived))).ReturnsAsync(new Activity());

    Activity result = await repo.Get(ID, User);

    ActivitiesMock.Verify(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == ID && y.Recruiter.CompanyID == User.CompanyID && (!y.Archived || IsArchived)));
}
```

(I know there are different ways of writing it, this is the most recent iteration we've tried.)

The `ActivitiesMock` relates to the `collection` found in `Get(long ID, Recruiter User, bool IsArchived = false)`. We recently wrote wrappers in order to try and test our Entity calls more efficiently, but we're running into this error when trying to verify the calls are made correctly:

> Test method ExampleProject.Tests.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepositoryTests.GetDoesThings threw exception: 
>   Moq.MockException: 
>   Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => (y.ID == .ID && y.Recruiter.CompanyID == .User.CompanyID) && (!(y.Archived) || .IsArchived))
>
> Configured setups:
>   x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => (y.ID == .ID && y.Recruiter.CompanyID == .User.CompanyID) && (!(y.Archived) || .IsArchived)), Times.Never
>
> Performed invocations:
>   IAppCollection`2.FirstOrDefault(x => (((x.ID == value(ExampleProject.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepository+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).ID) AndAlso (x.Recruiter.CompanyID == value(ExampleProject.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepository+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).User.CompanyID)) AndAlso (Not(x.Archived) OrElse value(ExampleProject.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepository+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).IsArchived)))

In this instance the wrapper (`collection`) is a mock of the interface. The goal is to ensure that the repository is calling the correct expression on the wrapper, so that we know the predicate that's being passed to the Entity DbSet is correct without having to worry about all the messy async abstractions.

The Mock `Setup()` with the full predicate doesn't appear to be found when the test is ran, and when I change the `Setup()` to `It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Activity, bool>>>()` it runs the mock and provides the return, but the `Verify` call doesn't work. So, running:

```
ActivitiesMock.Setup(x => x.FirstOrDefault(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Activity, bool>>>())).ReturnsAsync(new Activity());

Activity result = await repo.Get(ID, User);

Assert.IsNotNull(result);
ActivitiesMock.Verify(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == ID && y.Recruiter.CompanyID == User.CompanyID && (!y.Archived || IsArchived)));
```

Passes the assert but fails the Verify, whereas running:

```
ActivitiesMock
    .Setup(x => x.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ID == ID && y.Recruiter.CompanyID == User.CompanyID && (!y.Archived || IsArchived)))
    .ReturnsAsync(new Activity())
    .Verifiable();

Activity result = await repo.Get(ID, User);

Assert.IsNotNull(result);
ActivitiesMock.Verify();
```

Fails on the assert.

It looks like it's failing because it's expecting the same object types. Am I trying to do something that Moq can't handle, or am I missing something that I need to do in order to get the verification to be correct?

By request, the concrete implementation of the LINQ-to-Entity wrapper (`collection`) is:

```
public Task<T> FirstOrDefault(Expression<Func<T, bool>> Predicate)
{
    return DbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(Predicate);
}
```

Though the wrapper itself isn't being used, but an interface for it is being mocked, and it's that mock that we're testing.

Comment: Is that call to `FirstOrDefault` the usual LINQ method?  If so, you can't mock it using Moq because it is an extension method.

Comment: It isn't. It's a wrapper around the LINQ-to-Entities method.

Comment: Your verifying that the default LINQ `FirstOrDefault` method is called, which it's not. Can you post your wrapper please?

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear. I'm not using the actual implementation of the wrapper but a mock of it. I'm trying to verify the repository makes the correct call to the wrapper. I can post an implementation, but I'm not sure it would be helpful since I'm using a mock of the interface.

Comment: I updated the question to include the implementation. As I said, it isn't being called, since the wrapper itself is being mocked and all we're looking to do is verify that the correct expression is being used.

Comment: If I set it up so that I can get the called predicates out and view them after a `ToString()` call I get this: `x => ((x.ID == value(Example.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepository+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).ID) AndAlso (x.Recruiter.CompanyID == value(Example.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepository+<>c__DisplayClass2_0).User.CompanyID))` and `x => ((x.ID == value(Example.Tests.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepositoryTests+<>c__DisplayClass6_0).ID) AndAlso (x.Recruiter.CompanyID == value(Example.Tests.Backend.Repositories.ActivityRepositoryTests+<>c__DisplayClass6_0).User.CompanyID))`.

Comment: Obviously that means it doesn't match because it's expecting the types to align. I don't want to answer it just yet in case I can find a way to make them compare correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is neither. Since the anonymous functions have to create class instances to store the data being provided, they create `DisplayClass` instances to hold the data. Since those instances are being created in different namespaces (among other things) they don't pass when Moq calls `.Equals` against them.

We solved this problem by writing our tests as such:

```
ActivitiesMock
    .Setup(x => x.Where(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Activity, bool>>>()))
    .Returns((Expression<Func<Activity, bool>> x) =>
    {
        actualPredicate = x;
        return queryMock.Object;
    });
```

Then creating valid and invalid activities to provide to the predicate to ensure it returns `true` or `false` correctly:

```
Assert.IsTrue(actualPredicate.Compile().Invoke(validActivity));
```

Granted for now it's a bit hacky, but at first glance it doesn't seem too much like a dumpster fire solution, and it's a way for us to ensure the calls being provided do what we expect them to, which is what we want.

Update (Sep 7th, 2016): So far this has been working well for us. We've ran into an issue where LINQ-to-Entity statements don't run as expected because the LINQ is case-sensitive and the SQL generated isn't, but since that isn't a deal breaker for us we're just fine.

Comment: If someone comes up with an answer that allows us to test the lambda expressions easily without needing to change the tests significantly I'll be glad to ask a new question/mark it correct.